# local repo from different folders

Tags: git, joomla

I am developing extensions for Joomla cms. And the files are located in different folders.
modules/mymodule  and language/lang ...

My question: is it possible to have a local git repo configured to track different folders. (Please notice that I don't want to initiate the repo on the root cms folder).

Is there any best practices on git and Joomla extension development.

Comment: Not sure how efficient a git ignore file would be in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you should just create a simple repo dedicated to your plugin. Then, when you want to test it, you just need to install it on a test Joomla instance: the Joomla installer will take care of installing each file where it need to be. Anyway, you shouldn't create your git repo in the Joomla website.

As an example, here is a git repo of a joomla extension: https://github.com/elgolem/githubbadgejoomla